# Skipping value in CSS box model value definitions

Tags: css

**TLDR;**

I have a CSS input form which consists of 4 number inputs for each direction and it sets margins. When I submit **auto**, auto margins make element positioned in center horizontally. When I give **0px**, It sets it to 0px which is really a value of "0px", and it doesn't provide an auto like untouched property. Is this possible?

---

I wondered if there is something like this: For example I have a CSS definition like this:

```
border-width: 4px;
```

and on some case I want to change the width of only left and right borders:

```
border-left-width: 2px;
border-right-width: 2px;
```

Instead of writing this, I can't write these:

```
border-width: initial 2px;
border-width: inherit 2px;
border-width: unset 2px;
```

because they seem to be invalid values in chrome developer tools.

Is there anything else I can use to do this?

```js
function toggleClasses(){
  document.querySelectorAll(".div").forEach(function(elem){
    elem.classList.toggle("toggled");  
  });
  
}
```

```css
.div {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px; 
   margin: 20px;
   display: inline-block;
   background: #eee;
   border-color: #333;
   border-width: 4px;
   border-style: solid;   
}

.div.div-1.toggled {
   border-width: initial 2px;
   margin: initial 10px;
}

.div.div-2.toggled {
   border-width: inherit 2px;
   margin: inherit 10px;
}

.div.div-3.toggled {
   border-width: unset 2px;
   margin: unset 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div div-1"></div>
<div class="div div-2"></div>
<div class="div div-3"></div>
<input type="button" onclick="toggleClasses();" value="Togggle" />
```

Comment: What is it exactly that you want to achieve, atleast I didn't quite understand the problem?

Comment: Not in pure CSS, no. It's possible that there are CSS preprocessors which handle this, but even then, they'll have to compile this to the verbose version.

Comment: @Esko I think the question is if `border-width: 'previously defined value' 2px` is somehow possible.

Comment: I need a shortcut to give a css property (which supports 4 values like margins, paddings, borders etc) 4 values and only change less than 4 properties. Some values should be transparent.

Comment: By the way, none of the keywords in your attempt would have the intended effect. `border-top-width: initial` is not the same as "leaving it unchanged" after setting the width to 4px in an earlier rule. Same for `unset`, `initial` etc.

Comment: Yea I know, I listed the possibilities.